# how to control back in the same method from where $modal was opened in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a controller method from where I open $modal popup. Now if I close my popup then I need my control back to the function from where I opened the popup.

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('TechHealApp').controller('Dashboard', function ($scope,$modal) {

    $scope.openPopUp = function (templateUrl, controller, size) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: templateUrl,
                controller: controller,
                size: size,
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {

            }, function () {

        });
    };

    $scope.openIt = function () {
        $scope.openPopUp('abc.html', 'controllerA', 'sm');
        // I need my control here after closing the popup

    };          
});
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Yes. inside your modalInstance.result.then....put a logger like so console.log(selectedItem);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `openPopUp` function return promise (`modalInstance.result`) and use it in `openIt` function:

```
$scope.openPopUp = function(templateUrl, controller, size) {
    return $modal.open({
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
        controller: controller,
        size: size,
    }).result;
};

$scope.openIt = function() {
    $scope.openPopUp('abc.html', 'controllerA', 'sm').then(function(data) {
        // popup was closed (ok)
    }, function() {
        // popup was dismissed (cancel)
    });
};
```

Now, when closing popup from `controllerA` you can pass additional data and use it in then callbacks (note `data` parameter):

```
 // in controllerA when need to close modal
 $modalInstance.close({something: 123});
```

Comment: What if I have to return something from controllerA to Dashboard ?

Comment: You can do it. When you close popup (or dismiss) you can pass some data to it and it will be available in `then` callbacks. See updated answer.